# Store Javascript element value calculation in variable

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I would like to store the result of a calculation done in a Javascript function in a variable to be used for later, any way to do this?

This calculation is performed to show the user the sum of his/her selection in an HTML form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateCDiskInput(val) {
document.getElementById('CDiskInput').value=val*150;
}
</script>
```

Can the result of this calculation be stored in a variable for later use?

Comment: When do you call the function? If you let me know I'll make my answer more specific for you.

Comment: Hi! And thanks for trying to help! Code:
In header:
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateCDiskInput(val) {                                               document.getElementById('CDiskInput').value=val*150;
}
</script>

Comment: In HTML Form                                                          <input name="extendc" type="range" min="0" max="960" value="0" step="10" style="width: 80%" onchange="updateCDiskInput(this.value);">
                                                                              <output for="extendc">0</output>                                                   
</div>
                                                                         <input class="calc" type="text" id="CDiskInput" value="0">

Comment: Okay - although it isn't the most graceful method, the second of my examples will work for you - declare the global `var result;` and set it each time the function is called. `result` will always be the value calculated in the last `onchange` event.

Comment: Thanks! Yes it is probably not the best code, I've only just started to work with Javascript. (I'm a VI admin, not a webdev, but I need a webtool which includes this code for my work and since I didn't find anything suitable I'm making it on my own)

Answer (score 1):

You can put the result in a variable:

```
function updateCDiskInput(val) {
    return document.getElementById('CDiskInput').value=val*150;
}

var result = updateCDiskInput(1);
```

You could update a variable from within the function, but that is more volatile as your code will be temporally coupled (when you use the value, you would have to know if the function had run or not).

```
var result;

function updateCDiskInput(val) {
    result = document.getElementById('CDiskInput').value=val*150;
}
```

Comment: first approach is a lot better. in second example you don't even need a function

Comment: @LorDex I don't know where the function is called from in either example (i.e. is it called based on an event and the result should then be stored). Something must be passing `val`. In the first one, I'm assuming the `result` variable would be in the place where the function is called... not straight after the function is declared.